# Remove similar tuple from dictionary of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have dictionary of tuples as shown:
mydict =
{0: (12, 89), 1: (23, 78), 2: (34, 67), 3: (45, 56), 4: (56, 45), 5: (67, 34), 6: (78, 23), 7: (89, 12)}

Here, the last four elements (56, 45), (67, 34), (78, 23), (89, 12) are duplicates of the first four elements, but arranged in a different order and i want to remove it.

I'm using the below approach, but this will remove only if the tuples are same. Eg: (12, 89) = (12, 89).

```
values = mydict.values()
for x, y in mydict.items():
   for i in values:
         if i not in mydict.items():
             print("Result", x, y)
```

What is the efficient way to get the desired result ?  I want to compare maybe for example (12, 89) and (89, 12) and since it has same elements in it i want to remove one of them.

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Comment: You need to make a new dict where all the values are sorted. This will make the ‘==‘ comparison work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your options depend on if you care about the order of the tuples, after the deletion and if your input dictionary is ordered (python 3.6+).

### No ordering

#### Solution 1 (Python 3.6+)

In case you do not care about the order and using python 3.6+, you can use the following trick:

```
filtered = {tuple(sorted(val)): key for key, val in mydict.items().__reversed__()}
restored = {val: key for key, val in filtered.items()}
```

```
{0: (12, 89), 1: (23, 78), 2: (34, 67), 3: (45, 56)}
```

The idea is built on the concept that python dict is sorted on 3.6+, this means that the first keys will be inserted later into the dict because of the `__reversed__` order. The first line reversed the key and value, hence any duplicate values will be overwritten (that is why we do it in reversed order, so the last elements are overwritten in earlier elements). The second line flips the key and value back.

An important note with the above solution is that the tuples are now sorted. This means that if you would have had `0: (89, 12)`, this would have become `0: (12, 89)` instead.

#### Solution 2 (Any version)

The first trick really depends on the information that the higher key values can be eliminated by replacing them with the lower key values. In order to assure that condition, we can generate an ordered structure by sorting them based on the sorted value (`x[1]`) and their key (`x[0]`).

```
ordered = sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: (sorted(x[1]), x[0])).__reversed__()
```

Which leads to the following ordering

```
[(4, (56, 45)), (3, (45, 56)), (5, (67, 34)), (2, (34, 67)), (6, (78, 23)), (1, (23, 78)), (7, (89, 12)), (0, (12, 89))]
```

Then re apply solution 1:

```
filtered = {tuple(sorted(val)): key for key, val in ordered}
restored = {val: key for key, val in filtered.items()}
```

We are done.

### Maintain order

#### Solution 1 (Python 3.6+)

```
filtered = {tuple(sorted(val)): key for key, val in mydict.items().__reversed__()}
restored = {val: mydict[val] for key, val in filtered.items()}
```

Similar to the first solution without order, but now uses the key, to get the original value from the first dictionary. Therefore the values will be the same, in other words `0: (89, 12)`, remains `0: (89, 12)`.

#### Solution 2 (Any version)

Similar as the solution in the unordered variant, we reuse the original dictionary to generate the correct indices.

```
ordered = sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: (sorted(x[1]), x[0])).__reversed__()
filtered = {tuple(sorted(val)): key for key, val in ordered}
restored = {val: mydict[val] for key, val in filtered.items()}
```

### Notes

In order to see the difference between the solutions it would be advised to swap the order of `0: (12, 89)` to `0: (89, 12)`.

Everything combined:

```
mydict = {0: (89, 12), 1: (23, 78), 2: (34, 67), 3: (45, 56), 4: (56, 45),
          5: (67, 34), 6: (78, 23), 7: (89, 12)}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filtered = {tuple(sorted(val)): key for key, val in mydict.items().__reversed__()}
    restored = {val: key for key, val in filtered.items()}
    print(restored)

    restored = {val: mydict[val] for key, val in filtered.items()}
    print(restored)

    ordered = list(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: (sorted(x[1]), x[0])).__reversed__())
    filtered = {tuple(sorted(val)): key for key, val in ordered}
    restored = {val: key for key, val in filtered.items()}
    print(restored)

    ordered = sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: (sorted(x[1]), x[0])).__reversed__()
    filtered = {tuple(sorted(val)): key for key, val in ordered}
    restored = {val: mydict[val] for key, val in filtered.items()}
    print(restored)
```

And the output using python 3.9:

```
{0: (12, 89), 1: (23, 78), 2: (34, 67), 3: (45, 56)}  # No order python 3.6+
{3: (45, 56), 2: (34, 67), 1: (23, 78), 0: (12, 89)}  # No order any version
{0: (89, 12), 1: (23, 78), 2: (34, 67), 3: (45, 56)}  # Order python 3.6+
{3: (45, 56), 2: (34, 67), 1: (23, 78), 0: (89, 12)}  # Order any version
```

### Edit

As indicated by `Jasmijn`, a more proper solution for when order doesn't matter would be to replace `tuple(sorted(val))` by `frozenset(val)`.

Comment: If order isn't important `frozenset` might be a more appropriate datatype than sorted `tuple`s.

Comment: That is indeed a better solution. I put in an edit it to the answer to indicate the option. Thank you!